# Where to put http get call inside a javascript promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using Elasticsearch and AngularJS to build a small search application. I'm trying to use Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead to implement an autocomplete feature using the http.get call for asynchronous results and am not exactly sure where to put it?.... still learning ES and Angular.

Where would I put this http.get call inside this js promise code?

http.get code:

```
return $http.get('localhost:9200/bigtestindex/doc/_search', {
      params: {
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "content.autocomplete": {
              "query": query,
              "default_operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }),
```

Javascript promise code:

```
this.getSuggestions = function(query) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  var terms = query.split(' '),
      baseTerms = terms.length === 1 ? '' : terms.slice(0, -1).join(' ') + ' ',
      lastTerm = terms[terms.length - 1].toLowerCase();

  esClient.search({
    index: 'bigtestindex',
    body: {
      "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
          "fields": ['title'],
          "query": baseTerms + '(' + lastTerm + '|' + lastTerm + '*)',
          "default_operator": "and"
        }
      },
      "suggest": {
        "text": query,
        "phraseSuggestion": {
          "phrase": {
            "field": "title",
            "direct_generator": [{
              "field": "title",
              "suggest_mode": "popular",
              "min_word_length": 3,
              "prefix_length": 2
            }]
          }
        }
      },
      "size": 5,
      "_source": ["content"]
    }
  }).then(function(es_return) {
    deferred.resolve(es_return);
  }, function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

I am pretty sure in goes in the body somewhere just not sure where... I can't get it to work.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're using elasticSearch JS client, you don't need to issue an $http call since the client does it for you.

Comment: Start by avoiding the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, your controller code could look like this:

```
function searchController(esClient)
{
     var ctl = this;
     ctl.suggestions = [];

     this.getSuggestions = function(query) {
         var terms = query.split(' '),
         baseTerms = terms.length === 1 ? '' : terms.slice(0, -1).join(' ') + ' ',
         lastTerm = terms[terms.length - 1].toLowerCase();

         esClient.search({
             index: 'bigtestindex',
             body: {
               "query": {
                 "simple_query_string": {
                   "fields": ['title'],
                   "query": baseTerms + '(' + lastTerm + '|' + lastTerm + '*)',
                   "default_operator": "and"
                 }
               },
               "suggest": {
                 "text": query,
                 "phraseSuggestion": {
                   "phrase": {
                     "field": "title",
                     "direct_generator": [{
                       "field": "title",
                       "suggest_mode": "popular",
                       "min_word_length": 3,
                       "prefix_length": 2
                     }]
                   }
                 }
               },
               "size": 5,
               "_source": ["content"]
             }
           }, function(err, es_return) {
               if(err) {
                  //Handle error or do nothing
                  return;
               }
               ctl.suggestions = es_return;
           });
       };
}
```

Comment: the answer is not exactly what I'm looking for but will accept it because it still applies